# Full screen UICollectionViewCell with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am looking to make an image gallery.  I want my images full screen but am not sure how this works with Auto Layout.  I know there is a method to return the size of a cell but didn't know if I should just be getting the screen size and returning it or if there was an approach with using Auto Layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell size in a collection view (or table view for that matter) isn't set with auto layout. You should set the size of the cell will the UICollectionViewFlowLayout method, itemSize. You can set the size of the collection view itself in IB (or code) with constraints, so it will adjust for different screen sizes, then set your cell size to be the same as the collection view's size.

Comment: how can I set the size of the collection cell same as collection view